# How to set left and right padding to an entry cell in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have used custom rendering for entry cell in xamarin forms for IOS and android. How can I set left and right padding for the entry cell.

My custom entry cell in PCl :

```
<local:MyEntryCell Placeholder="Placeholder" PlaceholderColor="Grey" TextColor="Black"/>

MyEntryCell is the custom name of my entry cell.
```

In my PCL I have:

```
public class MyEntryCell:Entry
{

}
```

In IOS:

```
namespace CustomEntry.IOS
{
   public class MyEntryCellRenderer:EntryRenderer
    {
         // override onElementChanged
    }
}
```

In Android :

```
namespace CustomEntry.Droid
    {
       public class MyEntryCellRenderer:EntryRenderer
        {
             // override onElementChanged
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your `MyEntryCell` inherit from? Can't you just use `Padding="10,0,10,0"`?

Comment: There is no padding attribute for entry cell

Comment: Then you will probably need to set some padding within your `MyEntryCell` could you please update your question with the code for your `MyEntryCell`?

Comment: Your entry cell is not an EntryCell but it derives from Entry. This is misleading since the available properties and the way how you build a custom renderer are completely different. Please adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this for setting padding to an entry cell:

Padding in IOS :

```
Control.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0,0,15,0));
Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
Control.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 15, 0));
Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

Padding in Android:

```
Control.SetPadding(15, 15, 15, 0);
```

Accordingly, you can set the value to make text start from specific position.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks !

Comment: Good one., Thanks for you answer.